# highlight.js inline mode possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was able to make a code-block with `highlight.js` like this:

```
<pre>
  <code class="haskell">
    {-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}
    euclid :: Int -> Int -> Int
    euclid a b
      | a == 0    = b
      | b == 0    = a
      | a > b     = euclid (a-b) b
      | otherwise = euclid a (b-a)
  </code>
</pre>
```

Works fine!
But now I also want to have some code lines in my text, inline.
Like this:

```
<p> Info text inline code testing <code class="haskell">{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}</code> maybe it works</p>
```

Doesn't work...
You can check them out at [my Site](http://tekkkz.com/posts/articles/arch_installation.html)

How to make inline code with `highlight.js` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just need a little CSS to make it inline. How you do it is up to you, but you could make it inline if it's within a `p` tag.

```
p > code.hljs { display: inline; }
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ykyLcvnw/1/

Comment: This becomes problematic if OP puts block code inside of a `<p>` tag.

Comment: How? The CSS selector only selects immediate `code.hljs` children of `p` elements to display inline. So long as the block code is inside of `<pre><code>` tags, it will be displayed as a block, even though it's preceded with a `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, you use both a `<pre>` and a `<code>` tag. This isn't the case in your second.

From the [highlight.js usage page](https://highlightjs.org/usage/):

> This will find and highlight code inside of `<pre><code>` tags;

I've additionally sourced this example from the usage page:

```
 $('pre code').each(function(i, block) {
   hljs.highlightBlock(block);
 });
```

Since your inline markup is in a `<span>` tag, that is, the hierarchy is `span code`, you can achieve inline highlighting with something like:

```
 $('span code').each(function(i, inline) {
   hljs.highlightBlock(inline);
 });
```

I ran this code in the console on your test page, and I'm seeing the results. Assuming you're not using jQuery, the pseudo code is just

1. iterate over all desired elements
2. apply hljs.highlightBlock(element)

Comment: What? I don't understand what you are talking about...?

Comment: your answer is 0 helpful! What does this has todo with inline highlighting??

Comment: Im saying for your second example, inline, you have a code tag inside a span. Wrap the code tag inside some pre tags and see if that helps!

Comment: No of course it wont, then its an block and not inline!

Comment: Edited answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It'll be much simpler if you define your own `inline` class in CSS like this

```
.inline{
    display: inline;
}
```

Then set your code tag's `class` attribute to `haskell inline`.
That's it, you can make it the same way for any other language by replacing `haskell` with your language of choice.